# php form send data to wrong mysql column

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to use add student form from student.php file. But after I hit add button from the form, the data are being saved to wrong column. Only student name and roll no. are correct. student_dob in mysql table only save 0000-00-00. Others either wrong place or no data at all.

Here are the student.php codes:

```
<?php

//student.php

include('header.php');

?>

<div class="container" style="margin-top:30px">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">Student List</div>
        <div class="col-md-3" align="right">
            <button type="button" id="add_button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <span id="message_operation"></span>
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="student_table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Student Name</th>
                        <th>Mykids</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Class</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/datepicker.css" />

<style>
    .datepicker {
      z-index: 1600 !important; /* has to be larger than 1050 */
    }
</style>

<div class="modal" id="formModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <form method="post" id="student_form">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal_title"></h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <label class="col-md-4 text-right">Student Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" name="student_name" id="student_name" class="form-control" />
                <span id="error_student_name" class="text-danger"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <label class="col-md-4 text-right">Roll No. <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" name="student_roll_number" id="student_roll_number" class="form-control" />
                <span id="error_student_roll_number" class="text-danger"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <label class="col-md-4 text-right">Date of Birth <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" name="student_dob" id="student_dob" class="form-control" />
                <span id="error_student_dob" class="text-danger"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <label class="col-md-4 text-right">Gender <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" name="student_gender" id="student_gender" class="form-control" />
                <span id="error_student_gender" class="text-danger"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <label class="col-md-4 text-right">Grade<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <select name="student_grade_id" id="student_grade_id" class="form-control">
                  <option value="">Select Grade</option>
                  <?php
                  echo load_grade_list($connect);
                  ?>
              </select>
              <span id="error_student_grade_id" class="text-danger"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <label class="col-md-4 text-right">Card No.<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" name="student_card" id="student_card" class="form-control" />
                <span id="error_student_card" class="text-danger"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="hidden" name="student_id" id="student_id" />
            <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="Add" />
            <input type="submit" name="button_action" id="button_action" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Add" />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>

      </div>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="deleteModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Confirmation</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h3 align="center">Are you sure you want to remove this?</h3>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" name="ok_button" id="ok_button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">OK</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var dataTable = $('#student_table').DataTable({
        "processing":true,
        "serverSide":true,
        "order":[],
        "ajax":{
            url:"student_action.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{action:'fetch'},
        }
    });

    $('#student_dob').datepicker({
        format:"yyyy-mm-dd",
        autoclose: true,
        container: '#formModal modal-body'
    });

    function clear_field()
    {
        $('#student_form')[0].reset();
        $('#error_student_name').text('');
        $('#error_student_roll_number').text('');
        $('#error_student_dob').text('');
        $('#error_student_gender').text('');
        $('#error_student_grade_id').text('');
        $('#error_student_card').text('');
    }

    $('#add_button').click(function(){
        $('#modal_title').text('Add Student');
        $('#button_action').val('Add');
        $('#action').val('Add');
        $('#formModal').modal('show');
        clear_field();
    });

    $('#student_form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:"student_action.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            dataType:"json",
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#button_action').val('Validate...');
                $('#button_action').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            },
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#button_action').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#button_action').val($('#action').val());
                if(data.success)
                {
                    $('#message_operation').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data.success+'</div>');
                    clear_field();
                    $('#formModal').modal('hide');
                    dataTable.ajax.reload();
                }
                if(data.error)
                {
                    if(data.error_student_name != '')
                    {
                        $('#error_student_name').text(data.error_student_name);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#error_student_name').text('');
                    }
                    if(data.error_student_roll_number != '')
                    {
                        $('#error_student_roll_number').text(data.error_student_roll_number);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#error_student_roll_number').text('');
                    }
                    if(data.error_student_dob != '')
                    {
                        $('#error_student_dob').text(data.error_student_dob);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#error_student_dob').text('');
                    }
                    if(data.error_student_gender != '')
                    {
                        $('#error_student_gender').text(data.error_student_gender);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#error_student_gender').text('');
                    }
                    if(data.error_student_grade_id != '')
                    {
                        $('#error_student_grade_id').text(data.error_student_grade_id);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#error_student_grade_id').text('');
                    }
                    if(data.error_student_card != '')
                    {
                        $('#error_student_card').text(data.error_student_card);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#error_student_card').text('');
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    });

  var student_id = '';

  $(document).on('click', '.edit_student', function(){
    student_id = $(this).attr('id');
    clear_field();
    $.ajax({
      url:"student_action.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:{action:'edit_fetch', student_id:student_id},
      dataType:"json",
      success:function(data)
      {
        $('#student_name').val(data.student_name);
        $('#student_roll_number').val(data.student_roll_number);
        $('#student_dob').val(data.student_dob);
        $('#student_gender').val(data.student_gender);
        $('#student_grade_id').val(data.student_grade_id);
        $('#student_card').val(data.student_card);
        $('#student_id').val(data.student_id);
        $('#modal_title').text('Edit Student');
        $('#button_action').val('Edit');
        $('#action').val('Edit');
        $('#formModal').modal('show');
      }
    })
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.delete_student', function(){
    student_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#deleteModal').modal('show');
  });

  $('#ok_button').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url:"student_action.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:{student_id:student_id, action:"delete"},
      success:function(data)
      {
        $('#message_operation').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
        $('#deleteModal').modal('hide');
        dataTable.ajax.reload();
      }
    })
  });

});
</script>
```

here is student_action.php (responsible to send data to mysql)

```
<?php

//student_action.php

include('database_connection.php');

session_start();

if(isset($_POST["action"]))
{
    if($_POST["action"] == "fetch")
    {
        $query = "
        SELECT * FROM tbl_student 
        INNER JOIN tbl_grade 
        ON tbl_grade.grade_id = tbl_student.student_grade_id 
        ";

        if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
        {
            $query .= '
            WHERE tbl_student.student_name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
            OR tbl_student.student_roll_number LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%"
            OR tbl_student.student_dob LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
            OR tbl_grade.grade_name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
            ';
        }

        if(isset($_POST["order"]))
        {
            $query .= '
            ORDER BY '.$_POST['order']['0']['column'].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].'
            ';
        }
        else
        {
            $query .= '
            ORDER BY tbl_student.student_id DESC 
            ';
        }
        if($_POST["length"] != -1)
        {
            $query .= 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
        }

        $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        $data = array();
        $filtered_rows = $statement->rowCount();
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $sub_array = array();
            $sub_array[] = $row["student_name"];
            $sub_array[] = $row["student_roll_number"];
            $sub_array[] = $row["student_gender"];
            $sub_array[] = $row["grade_name"];
            $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="edit_student" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm edit_student" id="'.$row["student_id"].'">Edit</button>';
            $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="delete_student" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete_student" id="'.$row["student_id"].'">Delete</button>';
            $data[] = $sub_array;
        }
        $output = array(
            "draw"              =>  intval($_POST["draw"]),
            "recordsTotal"      =>  $filtered_rows,
            "recordsFiltered"   =>  get_total_records($connect, 'tbl_student'),
            "data"              =>  $data
        );

        echo json_encode($output);
    }

    if($_POST["action"] == 'Add' || $_POST["action"] == "Edit")
    {
        $student_name = '';
        $student_roll_number = '';
        $student_dob = '';
        $student_gender = '';
        $student_grade_id = '';
        $student_card = '';
        $error_student_name = '';
        $error_student_roll_number = '';
        $error_student_dob = '';
        $error_student_gender = '';
        $error_student_grade_id = '';
        $error_student_card = '';
        $error = 0;
        if(empty($_POST["student_name"]))
        {
            $error_student_name = 'Student Name is required';
            $error++;
        }
        else
        {
            $student_name = $_POST["student_name"];
        }
        if(empty($_POST["student_roll_number"]))
        {
            $error_student_roll_number = 'Student Roll Number is required';
            $error++;
        }
        else
        {
            $student_roll_number = $_POST["student_roll_number"];
        }
        if(empty($_POST["student_dob"]))
        {
            $error_student_dob = 'Student Date of Birth is required';
            $error++;
        }
        else
        {
            $student_dob = $_POST["student_dob"];
        }
        if(empty($_POST["student_gender"]))
        {
            $error_student_dob = 'Student Gender is required';
            $error++;
        }
        else
        {
            $student_dob = $_POST["student_gender"];
        }
        if(empty($_POST["student_grade_id"]))
        {
            $error_student_grade_id = "Grade is required";
            $error++;
        }
        else
        {
            $student_grade_id = $_POST["student_grade_id"];
        }
        if(empty($_POST["student_card"]))
        {
            $error_student_card = "Card No. is required";
            $error++;
        }
        else
        {
            $student_grade_id = $_POST["student_card"];
        }
        if($error > 0)
        {
            $output = array(
                'error'                         =>  true,
                'error_student_name'            =>  $error_student_name,
                'error_student_roll_number'     =>  $error_student_roll_number,
                'error_student_dob'             =>  $error_student_dob,
                'error_student_gender'          =>  $error_student_gender,
                'error_student_grade_id'        =>  $error_student_grade_id,
                'error_student_card'            =>  $error_student_card
                );
        }
        else
        {
            if($_POST["action"] == 'Add')
            {
                $data = array(
                    ':student_name'         =>  $student_name,
                    ':student_roll_number'  =>  $student_roll_number,
                    ':student_dob'          =>  $student_dob,
                    ':student_gender'       =>  $student_gender,
                    ':student_grade_id'     =>  $student_grade_id,
                    ':student_card'         =>  $student_card
                );
                $query = "
                INSERT INTO tbl_student 
                (student_name, student_roll_number, student_dob, student_gender, student_grade_id, student_card) 
                VALUES (:student_name, :student_roll_number, :student_dob, :student_gender, :student_grade_id, :student_card)
                ";

                $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
                if($statement->execute($data))
                {
                    $output = array(
                        'success'       =>  'Data Added Successfully',
                    );
                }
            }
            if($_POST["action"] == "Edit")
            {
                $data = array(
                    ':student_name'         =>  $student_name,  
                    ':student_roll_number'  =>  $student_roll_number,
                    ':student_dob'          =>  $student_dob,
                    ':student_gender'       =>  $student_gender,
                    ':student_grade_id'     =>  $student_grade_id,
                    ':student_card'         =>  $student_card,
                    ':student_id'           =>  $_POST["student_id"]
                );
                $query = "
                UPDATE tbl_student 
                SET student_name = :student_name, 
                student_roll_number = :student_roll_number, 
                student_dob = :student_dob,
                student_gender = :student_gender,
                student_grade_id = :student_grade_id, 
                student_card = :student_card
                WHERE student_id = :student_id
                ";
                $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
                if($statement->execute($data))
                {
                    $output = array(
                        'success'       =>  'Data Edited Successfully',
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($output);
    }

    if($_POST["action"] == "edit_fetch")
    {
        $query = "
        SELECT * FROM tbl_student 
        WHERE student_id = '".$_POST["student_id"]."'
        ";
        $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
        if($statement->execute())
        {
            $result = $statement->fetchAll();
            foreach($result as $row)
            {
                $output["student_name"] = $row["student_name"];
                $output["student_roll_number"] = $row["student_roll_number"];
                $output["student_dob"] = $row["student_dob"];
                $output["student_gender"] = $row["student_gender"];
                $output["student_grade_id"] = $row["student_grade_id"];
                $output["student_card"] = $row["student_card"];
                $output["student_id"] = $row["student_id"];
            }
            echo json_encode($output);
        }
    }
    if($_POST["action"] == "delete")
    {
        $query = "
        DELETE FROM tbl_student 
        WHERE student_id = '".$_POST["student_id"]."'
        ";
        $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
        if($statement->execute())
        {
            echo 'Data Delete Successfully';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

please help..

Comment: I want to encourage you to put you HTML and JavaScript into separate files, furthermore you are not sanitizing any inputs and without comments or any form of explanation it's rather difficult to read your code.

Comment: I mean, for one, this seems like a pretty obvious error: `$student_dob = $_POST["student_gender"];`  Please take some time to review your code for mistakes like this.

Comment: I'm voting to close as a typo because there are a couple mis-assigned variables.